# How to restore Ubuntu in a new disk

Tags: backup, partitioning, clone, clonezilla

I have a dual boot system with windows 10 and Ubuntu. I would like to backup and restore only the functioning Ubuntu into a new disk,without windows. How should I proceed? I have used clonezilla and backup only the partition of Ubuntu but after restoring it, it didn't boot: I believe because I didn't backup the right partitions or copied the grub or whatsoever. Ps, I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward approach is to use `deja dup` to backup you user data and configuration files to a USB drive, do a clean install of Ubuntu, then restore all your data and config to that new install.

Sure, there are other ways...you could boot with a Live DVD, use `gparted` to delete the Windows partition, expand the Linux partition, then fix grub. You'd have to do the backup first anyway, and I be you end up doing the clean install anyway.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks. Could you please explain me which directory should I copy specifically? Should I use the 'tar' command? I would like to keep my programs if possible. If that is the case, I believe the easiest way would be to install a fresh copy and then restore the needed directory?

Comment: Well, that depends on your system. clearly, you have to backup `/home/user/`. `/etc`, `/usr`, `/var` and `/opt` are what I include. Some people say you should exclude copies of things you have in the cloud like your dropbox folder but I'd rather back it up and restore from a USB than wait for it to download over a wifi connection. You will have to reinstall any of your installed applications, but this is a good time to divest yourself of chaf of stuff you never really use.

Comment: Is there a way to restore all the programs I have installed on my original Ubuntu as well?

Comment: There's an application called `aptik` which can do that. It will also handle the backup of your settings, config files, and your home directory. I've used it exactly once to copy everything from my main Ubuntu machine to a notebook. It worked, but since I've only used it once, my data set is limited.  Here's a link for you, a place to start: https://www.howtogeek.com/206454/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-apps-and-ppas-in-ubuntu-using-aptik/

Comment: Sounds perfect to me. I will definitely take a look at it! Thanks again Marc!

Comment: If the answer was useful then please accept it. This is how it works.